# GitLab: Deploy keys are not allowed to push

Tags: git, gitlab

I have Existing project folder that contains git  , when i need to push it i face this issue

```
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (54.93.71.23)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is   
SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

**Note** I was working well with git and the same project on fedora 21
         but when update to fedora 22 this issue appeared.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure the host matches what you expect, and that the key fingerprint is what you expect (the key fingerprint should be posted in GitLab's docs), and continue by typing `yes` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

You're seeing this because you've never connected to that host before.

Comment: you right Madara Uchiha , the issue is determine the key fingerprint 
i was adding it on the project not on my profile ,  from along time i did not deploy a new key .

Comment: "what you expect" is a bit vague: Check https://gitlab.com/help/instance_configuration for the correct fingerprints.